# Memcached in front of Subscription Database

Tags: nservicebus

I'm wondering if it's possible to throw memcached in front of the subscription database.  I know NServiceBus is using NHibernate, which supports memcached.

We're running into some flaky issues with our subscription database, and since subscriptions rarely change, they would be an excellent candidate to be stored in memcached.

Answer (score 0):

If NHibernate supports it, it'll work.  You may want to consider have some redundancy built in and/or back it with the database.